# How to properly define query param input of array in Swagger so input fields shows in UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I would like to update my **Swagger** in a way the input field will be displayed in the UI of **Swagger**. The input field should accept a string containing comma-separated substrings (role IDs).
How can I achieve it? Is such a feature even supported by Swagger?

[image]

The schema:

```json
{
  "components": {},
  "info": {
    "contact": {},
    "description": "Offers user-related information.",
    "title": "User feature",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "paths": {
    "/user/user-management/find-users": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "FIND_USERS",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "roleIds",
            "required": false,
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "minItems": 1,
              "nullable": false,
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "content": {},
            "description": "Retrieve a list of users."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  ]
}
```